# Extra Layouts in View Hierarchy

Tags: android

I have a custom view in an activity that I want to stretch the full length of the screen. Unfortunately match_parent isn't working. I looked at the hierarchy and it seems there is and extra linear layout as you can see here

[image]

I don't know why the second linearlayout is there. I create the view like this.

```
public class TimeSlider extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView timeHandleTv;


    public TimeSlider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.time_slider, this, true);
        timeHandleTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeHandleTv);
    }
}
```

time_slider.xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeHandleTv"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@drawable/time_handle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Where is the extra linearlayout coming from?

**EDIT**

To be clearer this view does only have one textview. However the text view will move to different positions within the linearlayout. So it is necessary to have the linearlayout parent. As you can see with this code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int Y = (int) event.getY();
    if (Y < 1) {
        Y = 0;
    } else if(Y > getHeight() - timeHandleTv.getHeight()) {
        Y =  getHeight() - timeHandleTv.getHeight();
    }
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y;
            timeHandleTv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            timeHandleTv.setText(getTime());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y;
            timeHandleTv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            timeHandleTv.setText(getTime());
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I remove the linearlayout in the xml I do remove the extra linearlayout in the hierarchy. But if I had more than one view within the view how would I create it without having an extra linearlayout?

Comment: Try: this = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.time_slider, this, true);

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate the layout TimeSlider which is a LinearLayout becomes it's parent. In this line:

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.time_slider, this, true);
```

you ask to inflate the layout with the current object as parent. What you see in hierarchy is:

- TimeSlider class layout - LinearLayout
- LinearLayout from time_slider.xml
- TextView from time_slider.xml

Comment: are you saying that I shouldn't ask to inflate the layout with the current object as the parent?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want the custom view to have a LinearLayout and a TextView inside it's enough to have time_slider.xml only with the TextView object.

Comment: wow I was really expecting that not to work. So I have removed the extra linearlayout. The problem with the match_parent still exists but I guess the problem lies somewhere else. Out of interest how would I create a custom view with more than 1 view inside?

Comment: Everything that is inside time_slider.xml will be inflated in your custom LinearLayout. You can add there as many views as you want. Most likely your problem is where you use TimeSlider view. It should have match_parent and make sure its parent (if any exists) takes the whole screen.

Comment: but if I have more than one view, I would need to have a relativelayout out or linearlayout to arrange them. Then I have the problem with multiple layouts in the hierarchy

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood the question. I thought your custom view will be composed of multiple views. In that case my answer is correct and you have to wrap all of them in a layout object. If you wanted multiple views that don't have a common parent that's not possible because you are implementing a single custom view. The class can't represent views without a common parent as you would have many theoretical issues - where to send touches, how to draw and align them.

Comment: The way Android works is multiple views must have a common parent so you can't define multiple views without having a LinearLayout or any layout wrapping them. I believe it should all be fine if you put them in a layout and move them inside if that's what you need. The whole functionality is isolated in the custom view and will work as expected.